SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL inside mariadb event
I have a mariaDB event that runs every hour and copies data from multiple tables to others. Since I'm using INSERT INTO SELECT, and one of the tables is quite big, I end up having deadlocks, because one "insert into select" in one of the tables is taking too long, and the table is currently used in a production environment.
If I change TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL to READ UNCOMMITTED in the beginning of the event, I no longer have deadlocks, and the possible data inconsistencies are no problem to me, but I'm not sure if I'm changing the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL just for this event session (is there such a thing?), or if I'm changing the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL on a higher level (and possibly changing it for all the sessions?).
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT event_name
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
STARTS '2024-05-23 21:00:00'
DO
BEGIN
    SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    /*<sql code>*/
    SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ; /* resetting to the previous value*/
END$$

I found no information regarding changing the transaction isolation level on mariadb/mysql events. Does anybody have any information regarding this?
I know I have dozens of other options for this data copy job, but I currently have a time/resource constraint, and I can't handle it in another way.
Thank you all

Since you use the SESSION keyword, it's only for the current session, which is for that event.

Removed the mysql tags since this is specific to mariadb

Beware: reading uncommitted data can produce inaccurate results, since data may not be committed in the end, but you are using it anyway for who knows what purposes.

You are changing the transaction isolation level only for your current session.
Let me elaborate:
You have an RDBMS of MariaDB which is open for 0 or more connections.
One such connection creates a session. So, if you connect to your RDBMS via some program or the command-line, then you create a session for you and this kind of transaction isolation level modification only modifies the transaction isolation level on the level of your connection/session and leaves other connections intact.
So, since this is in the space of your MariaDB event, it should not affect anything else. But don't believe me, verify this yourself. Connect to your MariaDB and run this:
SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;

Connect to MariaDB again from another source, without disconnecting this one and run the command above.
Now, let's change the session transaction isolation level at one of the connections and rerun this command at the other. The plausible expectation is that the session transaction isolation level will be left intact in the other connection, but it will change in the connection where you changed it.
